# My </p> tag is affecting the position of my div. Why is this?

Tags: html, css

I have this div wedged between two bars(other divs), though when I add text into the equation, the div gets repositioned down.  It works as intended without the p element and its children.  Here's a fiddle to demonstrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/57uSQ/

this is the HTML that is causing the problem:

```
    <p>
        <span class="name">DOLCE & GABBANA</span>
        </br>
        <span class="title">THE ONE</span>
    </p>
```

And the correlating CSS:

```
.videoDesc {
    display: inline-block;

    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 0px;

    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
}

.videoDesc p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.videoDesc .name {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
}

.videoDesc .title {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
}

.title {
    font-family: Lekton;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

.name {
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align:top` to `.videoDesc`:

```
.videoDesc {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 0px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/57uSQ/1/)**

The default vertical alignment is baseline, which is causing the behavior you see.

Comment: Yep that did the trick.  I was a fool in assuming the default would have been top.  Thanks.